# Validate input in a text field with javascript (needs to be one of two values)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

long time reader, first time poster. I'm relatively new to Javascript, but I've been tinkering with HTML, PHP and SQL for a while now. Anyways, long story short my instructor at college gave us an assignment for some pseudocode, and I decided to see if I could make it into a working form with Javascript. I've already submitted my assignment, don't worry, you aren't helping me cheat. I just want to see if this can be done in Javascript, as impractical as it might be:

There's 3 classic movies on sale this week: 
1. Star Wars
2. E.T.
3. Raiders of the Lost Ark.

The user has to enter the number of the movie they want to see. If the value entered is <1 or >3, the page should return an error.

The user has the option to stream or download the movie, and needs to enter in a textbox S for streaming or D for downloading.

So far, what I need help with is validating the input from the streaming/downloading textbox. This is what I have for my code so far:

```
<p id="welcome">Welcome to MovieStream! Would you like to Stream or Download   
your movies? Type S for stream, D for download</p>
<form>
<input type="text" id="purchaseType">
<input type="submit" action="validateForm()">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {

if (document.getElementById("purchaseType").value != S || D) {
    alert("Please type S to stream the movie, or D to download");
}
}
</script>
```

So far this is as far as I've gotten. When I click submit, nothing happens (I've even tried

```
document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML += "Please type S to stream the movie, or D to Download");
```

but it still doesn't work. I think it's something with the ".value != S || D" area but I can't seem to find any information anywhere. Is this operation even possible in Javascript alone? I really hope this makes sense, and someone will hopefully have an answer for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the input with wished values as strings:

`if (document.getElementById("purchaseType").value != 'S' && document.getElementById("purchaseType").value != 'D') {`

(the single quotes)

**UPDATE:**

Here are the parts you need to change:

- to prevent sending the form to the server you need the `onsubmit` callback
- replace the `#error` contents instead of appending the (same) error message after each click

```js
function validateForm() {

    if (document.getElementById("purchaseType").value != 'S' && document.getElementById("purchaseType").value != 'D') {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please type S to stream the movie, or D to download";

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" id="purchaseType">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<p id="error"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I tried this but it still isn't working? Here's the page uploaded to my school server if you'd like to view the full source code, I've added a bit of stuff to it now:

deptcis7.fvtc.edu/500122783/demo.html

Comment: I updated my answer so it should behave more like you wish.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! The only problem is that the <p id="error" stays there even after changing the value of the text field to a valid input, but it's just a sample I'm trying to mess around with so I can live with it. Thanks a bunch! I'll have to look into the return false; and return true; things, that might have been what I was missing (as well as the form action). Anyways, thanks a ton!

edit: I changed it from writing to the <p> element to an alert window and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to remove the error message as soon as valid input was entered, you will need an event listener for the keyup event on the input field.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `pattern` attribute to the `input` element like this:

```
  <input type="text" id="purchaseType" pattern="S|D" required>
```

Then, if you want to customize the error message, check the `validity` property when an `input` event is raised on it:

```
purchaseType.addEventListener( "input", function ( event ) 
{
  if ( purchaseType.validity.patternMismatch ) 
    purchaseType.setCustomValidity( "Please type S to stream the movie, or D to download" ) 
  else 
    purchaseType.setCustomValidity( "" )
} )
```

Finally, add CCS rules with pseudo-element `:invalid` that will give a visual feedback, for example:

```
#purchaseType:invalid {
  color: red ;
  border: 1px solid  red ;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 red  ;
  }

#purchaseType:valid {
  color: limegreen ;
  border: 1px solid limegreen ;
  }
```

Reference: [MDN Data Form Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

```js
purchaseType.addEventListener( "input", function ( event ) 
{
  if ( purchaseType.validity.patternMismatch ) 
    purchaseType.setCustomValidity( "Please type S to stream the movie, or D to download" ) 
  else 
    purchaseType.setCustomValidity( "" )
} )
```

```css
#purchaseType:invalid {
  color: red ;
  border: 1px solid red ;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 red  ;

  }

#purchaseType:valid {
  color: limegreen ;
  border: 1px solid limegreen ;
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px 0 limegreen;
  }


#purchaseType:focus {
  outline: none ;
}
```

```html
<p id="welcome">Welcome to MovieStream! Would you like to Stream or Download   
your movies? Type S for stream, D for download</p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="purchaseType" pattern="S|D" required placeholder="Type S or D" autofocus>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```